# Is it possible to retrieve LinkedIn Posts / Shares based on keywords from the API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I know scraping LinkedIn is not permitted. But I see that you're able to retrieve shares based on someone's profile ID, but is it also possible to retrieve shares based on keywords?
Or is there a workaround where I can first get all profile ID's / Vanitynames based on a specific search and then get the shares / post content based on these ID's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know linkedin is very strict in scrapping their data. I think there is no retrieving based on keyword. You can retrive all then , use filter to sort.